# Alternatives to update rows

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, time-series

I have the following sample data:

|  | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021/05 | 50 |
| 1 | 2021/06 | 60 |
| 2 | 2021/07 | 70 |
| 3 | 2021/08 | 80 |
| 4 | 2021/09 | 90 |
| 5 | 2021/10 | 100 |

I want to update the data in the 'date' column, where for example '2021/05' becomes '05/10/2021', '2021/06' becomes '06/12/2021' and so long (I have to choose the new date manually for every row).

Is there a better/more clever way to do it instead of:

```
for i in df.index:
    if df['date'][i] == '2021/05':
        df['date'][i] = '05/10/2021'
    elif df['date'][i] == '2021/06':
        df['date'][i] = '06/12/2021'
```

The problem is that there are more than hundred rows that have to be updated and the code above will be tremendously long.

Comment: Do you have some kind of data structure or file containing what rows need to change to what?

Comment: How do you decide which month to set: 10, 12,?

Comment: I am making that choice. The data that I have is incomplete - it contains only year/month, so I have to manually assign the day also. But the thing is that using the code that I gave as an example will be too long (more than 100 lines for sure)

Comment: Try [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)?

Comment: Is 06/12/2021 June 12th, or December 6th (according to your data)?

Comment: is there a rule for selecting the day? Why `2021/06` becomes `06/12/2021` and not `06/11/2021`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [`select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) method from `numpy` like so :

```py
import numpy as np


condlist = [df['date'] == '2021/05', 
            df['date'] == '2021/06']

choicelist = ['05/10/2021',
              '06/12/2021']            

df['date'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an interactive approach, saving the amended `DataFrame` to a file at the end:

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.DataFrame({"date":["2021/05", "2021/06", "2021/07", "2021/08", "2021/09", "2021/10"], "value": [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]})

for n, i in enumerate(dt.loc[:,"date"]):
    to_be_parsed = True
    while parsed:
        day = input("What is the day for {:s}?".format(i))
        date_str = "{:s}/{:0>2s}".format(i, day)
        try:
            dt.loc[n,"date"] = pd.to_datetime("{:s}/{:0>2s}".format(i, day)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            to_be_parsed = False
        except:
            print("Invalid date: {:s}. Try again".format(date_str))

output_path = input("Save amended dataframe to path (no input to skip): ")
if len(output_path) > 0:
    dt.to_csv(output_path, index=False)
```